# Link under image not clickable

Tags: html, css, animation, hyperlink, click

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FtQ4d/1/

I'm doing a project for class, and I've made a webpage where there is a title in the center and two images of a left and right hand underneath. Upon hovering over one of the hands, it will move off of the screen revealing a link underneath. I've got the link hidden under the hands, but when the hand moves, the link is not clickable. How can I make it so?

Here are the relevant parts of the html and css:

```
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com"><p id="rsm">(view my resume.)</p></a>
    <div id="ind_wrap">
        <p id="ind">INDEX.HTML</p>
        <img src="r_hand.png" id="r_hand"/>
        <img src="l_hand.png" id="l_hand"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#r_hand{
background-image:url("rhand.png");
margin-top:-28%;
margin-left:50%;
height:100%;
width:35%;
animation:fr_bottom 4s 1;
}
#r_hand:hover{
animation:m_right 4s 1;
}
#l_hand{
margin-top:-52%;
margin-left:8%;
height:100%;
width:35%;
animation:fl_bottom 4s 1;
}

#l_hand:hover{
animation:m_left 3s 1;
}
#rsm{
margin-top:40%;
margin-left:20%;
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
}
```

So, `#rsm` is the link underneath that is revealed when the left hand moves out of it's way, but it is not clickable. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you make aJSFiddle to show us is actually happening? My guess is that the div is sitting on top of the link and since the div isn't actually moving (it would appear) then the link would not be clickable through the div.

Comment: Fiddle created. As you can see, the link is not clickable.

Comment: Where is the link to your fiddle

Comment: On top of the post. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the z-index value on #rsm. On hover change it to more positive so that it is rendered above all others

Comment: It didn't work when I changed the z-index on #rsm:hover but it is clickable when I change the z-index just on #rsm. Is there a way to make it work the way I want it? Edit: I tried changing the z-index in the #l_hand:hover animation to negative 9, but that still doesn't make the link clickable.

Comment: If you put the link AFTER the images in the div in the HTML source, you can then target it with a hover state.

Comment: Oh, man! It works! Thanks a lot! I'm not sure who to mark the "question answered" checkmark for though. 0_0

Comment: BTW, do you know why when I hover over the right hand both of the hands move down?

Comment: You could do this easily with css. But your markup is surely not the right way to go. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve from your fiddle. Can you make it more specific?

Answer (score 0):

As Arun mentioned in his answer, the z-index is responsible for this however a simple hover didn't work (I assume you don't want to use js).

Are you using Firefox or Chrome? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886656/webkit-transform-blocking-link) might be somehow related to your problem.

Also if you are centering elements please use `margin: 0 auto;` instead of manually tinkering with percentages to fit your screen size. I would also recommend you only use percentages for width not height as it may yield unexpected results on different screen dimensions.

**Edit:**

I hadn't realised the code in the fiddle is different from the one you posted. I also updated my answer.

Comment: I changed the code in the fiddle a little bit so the link was actually underneath the hand. And, I had to put the images on imgur so the img src is from there. Also,    margin:0 auto puts the text on the left side of my screen. maybe I'm doing it wrong.