# CSS card flip animation for WebKit browsers prevents links from functioning

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I'm trying to figure out how to create a card flip animation that triggers when you click anywhere on the front face of the card and flips back when the mouse leaves.

I have the basic animation working, but the problem is that both sides of the card contain links that seem to be 'blocked' by the animation. Right-clicking on a link works, but directly clicking on one just triggers the animation.

How would I go about modifying what I have to get the links to fire correctly?

A live demo of the issue is available on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/O-I/pen/nmrvH). Code is listed below for convenience, as well.

#### HTML

```
<div class='flip'>
  <div class='card'>
    <div class='front face'>
      <a href='http://periphery.in'><h3>Rahul</h3></a>
    </div>
    <div class='back face'>
      <a href='http://github.com/O-I'><h3>O-I</h3></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  height: 365px;
  width: 252px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.flip .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}

.flip .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -4px;
  top: -4px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.75s;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flip .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.back.face {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

#### JQuery

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
  $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('flipped');
  });
  return false;
});
```

I've seen a similar issue discussed on this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886656/webkit-transform-blocking-link) and in this [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=54371), but I'm still having trouble getting my specific example to work. Any leads in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked and fixed your CodePen (**EDIT**: moved it to JSbin so the link action would prove to work).

### [Here's the awesomeness](http://jsbin.com/aDUjOmib/1)

### CSS Changes:

```
h3 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Either that or make it a `<span>` lol

### Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.flip', function(){
  $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('flipped');
  });
  return false;
});
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(evt) {
  var e = evt || window.event;
  var clickedOn = (e.currentTarget) ? e.currentTarget : e.srcElement;
  e.stopPropagation();
  window.location.href = clickedOn.href;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. You didn't have to go through the trouble of forking my CodePen — it's just a bare-bones example of what I'm working with — but this working sample code really helps me get past the point at which I was stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the click event from propagating from your link to the card. Add this js code:

```
$('.flip a').on('click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: There's more than that though.  The H3 tag is huge (it is inside the a tag), so most of the card is the link.  So they also need to make the h3 a bit smaller so that it's hit area isn't almost the entire face of the card.

Comment: That's a subjective decision for the OP to decide. I would agree that I would do that, but that part does not address the OP's question. The question was how to stop clicks on the link from flipping the card, and my answer addressed this question.

Comment: @mayabelle Upvoted. You got to the crux of my problem quickly and succinctly. I don't think I would have known to pin point stopPropagation without some outside help. Thanks for helping me get unstuck.

Comment: @Fernker Good point about the h3 tag. This is just an example, but thanks for pointing out a potential issue that I should be aware of.