# Anchor tags non-clickable after adding a class and doing a 3d transform on the X-axis

Tags: jquery, css, sass, transform, css-transforms

In the inspector, the  tags are all still highlighted in the correct position and I am at a loss for what's going on. I've tried adding a ::before pseudo element, changing the z-index to 9999, and tons of googling. I've created a codepen that demonstrates the issue, as well as has some commented out specific notes in the JS module. Any and all help is appreciated.

Here's the markup, scss, and js to get the button to flip:

HTML:

```
    <div class="flip-container">
      <button class="story-button">
          <a class="front" href="http://google.com">Even A Button</a>
          <a class="back" href="http://google.com">Can Tell A Story</a>
      </button>
    </div>
```

SCSS:

```
// Story Button Styles
$StoryButtonWidth: 18em;
$StoryButtonHeight: 3em;
.flip-container {
    display: block; width: 100%; height: $StoryButtonHeight; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 0; position: relative; background: transparent;
}
.story-button { 
    display: block; width: $StoryButtonWidth; height: $StoryButtonHeight; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 0; position: relative; text-align: center; color: white; text-tranform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; z-index: 8000; @include flippy;
  > a { 
    display: block; width: 100%; height: $StoryButtonHeight; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 1em; float: left; clear: both; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: $StoryButtonHeight; color: $black;
    // &::before {
    //  content: ''; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999;
    // }
    &.front {
      background: $light-grey; z-index: 999; transform-origin: bottom center;
    }
    &.back { 
      position: absolute; top: ($StoryButtonHeight*-.5); background: darken($light-grey, 10%); z-index: -999; transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0,(-$StoryButtonHeight/2)); transform-origin: center center;
    }
  }
   // Rotate The Cube
  &.flip {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translate(0,$StoryButtonHeight);
    // > a {
    //  &.back {
    //      z-index: 9999;
    //  }
    }
  }
}
```

JS:

```
// Flip Button
$('.flip-container').hover(function () {
      $(this).children('.story-button').toggleClass('flip');
      return false;
});
```

[Example CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/andandandandrew/pen/EagxeL)

Comment: I didn't get a chance to look into it too much, but perhaps the responses from this question might apply to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886656/webkit-transform-blocking-link ; apologies in advance if that doesn't help!

Comment: Thanks for the try, but I tried the translating the <a> 1px to try and realign and it didn't solve anything. Everything is rotating perfectly now, it's just not clickable after it's flipped. I'm not sure if it's because the rotation messes with the position of the <a>'s, but when you inspect in dev tools it looks as though it's in the right spot. I'm going to tweet it out and see if I can get any bites. Thanks!

Comment: I found this pen: http://codepen.io/laserfalconkickass/pen/Hyitk?editors=110 and now I'm updating my markup to be more like that example. I think I may have been over complicating my markup.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with an all css solution. My markup was too bulky before.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="story-button"><b aria-hidden="true">Face One</b><!--Face One Needs To Be Repeated Here To Make Flip Correctly, I put it in a <b> and se visibility:hidden; on it-->
  <span class="flip-container">
    <span class="front">Face One</span>
    <span class="back">Face Two</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

SCSS:

```
// Flippy Button
$StoryButtonHeight: 3em;

.story-button {
   display: inline-block; padding: 1em 2em; color: $white; position: relative; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none;
  b {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

.flip-container {
  width: 100%; height: $StoryButtonHeight; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; transform-style: preserve-3d; transition: $cubic250; 
  &:hover { 
    top: (-$StoryButtonHeight/2); transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  span {
    display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; text-align: center; line-height: $StoryButtonHeight;
    &.front {
      top: 0; left: 0; background-color: red; transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ($StoryButtonHeight);
    }
    &.back {
      top: ($StoryButtonHeight/2); left: 0; background-color: blue; transform-origin: center top; transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(($StoryButtonHeight/2));
    }
  }
}
```

Codepen:

http://codepen.io/andandandandrew/pen/azmdxo?editors=110