# <a> tags not working in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, hyperlink

I am working on a small Codepen project for practice, below is the code in question:

```
<div class="social-links">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/367287/twitter.svg">
    </a>
    <a href="https://medium.com/" target="_blank">
        Link
    </a>
    <a href="https://medium.com/" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/367287/medium.svg">
   </a>
   <a href="https://medium.com/" target="_blank">
       <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/367287/medium.svg">
   </a>
</div>
```

The full code pen is here: http://codepen.io/SethHerning/pen/2ecd822daae0fecbdd7b6cafa664b6d7?editors=1100#0 (lines 18-32).

All the links work in Firefox and Edge, though the first two do not in Chrome or Opera.  I've run the code through a validator and the only error is no alt attribute on the img tags.  What am I missing that all the links are not working?

Comment: What is a non-working link? What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing the 50% blocking issue defined in here: [webkit transform blocking link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886656/webkit-transform-blocking-link)

There's a workaround though, in your CodePen modify your css by adding the specific Chrome style `-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px)`:

```
.member:hover > div {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
}
```

This is the bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=54371